# Visual Studio 2019 - Chrome freezes when clicking an HTML entry in the Network Tab of Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue debugging a simple web app in Google Chrome 87 with Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.1). The debugger starts and Chrome opens fine. When I open Dev Tools (F12) and go to the Network tab, I can see all of the HTML, JS, images, etc. just fine. If I click any entry ***except*** for an HTML file, I can see the Headers, Preview, Response, etc. for the file. If I click any HTML file, Chrome completely freezes and I have to shut down the browser/end the debugging session.

I noticed if I end the "Node.js: Server-side JavaScript" task in Task Manager while Chrome is locked/frozen, Chrome immediately un-freezes and I can debug again. What could be causing this issue? If I restart the debug session, the Node.js task automatically starts again.

**Clicking the highlighted entry causes Chrome to freeze:**

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

**Ending the Node.js task un-freezes Chrome:**

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: Typically, it's because you are calling a Node.js route (like GET /) but not responding to the browser with `res.send(...)`. So the browser is stuck because the request remains pending. Hard to tell more without seeing any bit of code.

Comment: It happens with any MVC web app I debug in Chrome. Not specific to any particular code that’s called.

Comment: Also, I’m not even using Node.js in the app. The Node.js server process starts automatically as part of VS 2019.

Comment: Ah, in this case I have no clue, sorry

Comment: @user2966445,did you try to run `devenv /safemode` under `Developer Command Prompt for VS` to start a pure VS to test whether your project has the same issue? Also, did you try to update Google and clean its cache?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT When I run safe mode, pretty much nothing works. I get an exception in Solution Explorer window ("Failed to create view...Could not load Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Managed.VS"), an exception is shown when opening a JS file ("There is no editor avaiable for 'abc.js') and when I debug, I get: "Unable to start program 'http://localhost:54763' The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code. Run setup to install or repair debugger."

Is this just a corrupt VS install or something?

Comment: I'm probably having the same issue. The browser freezes **only when I have Script Debugging enabled** and open the Preview tab for a document query (HTML). I can look at Headers, Response and other tabs just fine. I got Chrome 96 and Visual Studio v16.11.5.

Comment: I'm having almost the same issue as Andrius R. It only freezes when I have Script Debugging enabled.  However, I can't see the anything in the response tab either. Instead, it indicates that the request is still in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Normally startup VS

**1)** disable any third party installed VS extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**2)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**. Also, you could make a backup of your settings

**3)** Delete all temporary files under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.x.xxx\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. After that, restart your project, build, try to debug again.

**5)** also, if you select **Silverlight Debug**, please disable it. See [this link](https://www.eugenechiang.com/2019/08/07/debugger-is-not-properly-installed-run-setup-to-install-or-repair-the-debugger/).

**6)** try another preview like **IE** or **Edge**.

**7)** If not, just delete the whole folder `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx` or rename it. Make a initial environment for VS, then restart VS to test again.

**8)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it to the latest version

Comment: I tried #1, #2, #4, #5 (this was already disabled), and #7 so far with no difference. I don't have admin rights to do #3 or #8. Chrome is the preferred browser for debugging, so I'm hoping to avoid suggestion #6. The freezing of Chrome described in the question happens with any solution AND it also happens when debugging using VS 2017 (I have both VS 2017 and VS 2019 installed at the moment). I tried to clear Chrome user data (%AppData%/Local/Google/Chrome) and that didn't help either.

Comment: Check whether you have installed any third party software or anti-virus software. If so, you should turn them off. Also, check your CPU usage under Task Manager. I wonder if it is the problem of your Cpu or memory.

Comment: I don't have admin rights to shut off third-party or anti-virus software. CPU and Memory seem to be fine.

Comment: Is the "Node.js: Server-side Javascript" component/process shared between VS 2017/VS 2019, or would each install use its own version?

Comment: They use the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Inspect** > **Network** > **Network Throttling** dropdown > set it to '**No throttling**'.

[image]